# What's a word for someone that is healthy that has a gender neutral, positive connotation?

Tags: single-word-requests, connotation

Hi I'm looking for a word that refers to someone who takes care of their health and physical well being that has a positive connotation and gender neutral. For example someone who reads a lot of books might be called a reader, someone who does a lot of learning might be called a student or learner, etc. there was already a question like this on the website before but it failed to ask for a positive connotation or gender neutrality. The first words that come to mind (and responses to the past question) were fitness fanatic, health nut, fitness freak, etc. but none of these sound very pleasant at all- they make someone sound like a crazy person. Athlete doesn't work either as it infers the person does a specific sport. Body builder is great but often brings to mind the image of an extremely muscular man. Does anyone here have any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: How casual or formal do you want the word to be?  P.S. I think you are asking for a noun, not an adjective - correct?

Comment: Note that, at least in the context of lighthearted banter, the terms such as *health nut* may be used without implying any criticism.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the adjective "health-conscious" - which can also be used as a noun.

From "[Word Hippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/health-conscious.html)":

> In health-conscious Los Angeles people only drink decaffeinated coffee and then only with milk.
>
> The bulk of his customers are health-conscious professionals.
>
> Juicing is fast becoming a way of life for the health-conscious at heart.
>
> Ultimately, both chains seem to be losing out to rivals that appeal overtly to the more health-conscious.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a single word term naming people having the particular attitude you are referring to. The best I can think of is an identification by means of a phrase using the adjective "**health-minded**". You'd have to say something like "**a health-minded individual/person**".

- **XXX** was a  health-minded person to a high degree but that didn't prevent the covid to do away with him.

Comment: Or **health-conscious**.

Comment: Are you sure LPH? "**health-minded**" does not sound idiomatic, and, on a cursory search, I can find no examples

Comment: @Greybeard Here is one instance:  […] should command the careful consideration of every health - minded person https://books.google.fr/books?id=aJDYmCAH6k4C&pg=PA23&dq=health-minded&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiB1raXtYntAhWQyYUKHZPgA-cQ6AEwCnoECGMQAg#v=onepage&q=health-minded&f=false Another one: health-minded individual https://books.google.fr/books?id=sL0i8rVXMNoC&pg=PA47&dq=health-minded&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiB1raXtYntAhWQyYUKHZPgA-cQ6AEwDXoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=health-minded&f=false

Comment: @KateBunting "health-conscious" is in fact much more frequent: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=health-conscious%2Chealth-minded&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chealth%20-%20conscious%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chealth%20-%20minded%3B%2Cc0